What happened to Kidpool during the Deadpool Corps fight?
At one point in Deadpool & Wolverine, the titular duo face off against the Deadpool Corps, an alliance of 100 Deadpool Variants working for Cassandra Nova. I found it very conspicuous that the only Corps member still standing at the end of the fight was Babypool, who is literally an infant, and that Deadpool and Wolverine made no attempt to attack them before the others regenerated and got back up. IIRC, hurting children is one of the few lines that comic book Deadpool refuses to cross, and clearly, the on-screen murder of an infant was one of the few lines the movie wouldn't cross.
This does raise the question of what happened to the other child participating in the fight, namely, Kidpool. I can't recall seeing Kidpool during the fight scene, so it's possible they were spared as well (or at least killed offscreen), but then again, I have ADHD and found it very difficult to keep track of what was going on at all during the fight, so it's also possible that they were killed on-screen and I just didn't notice.
So what happened to Kidpool? Were they spared like Babypool or "killed" like the rest of the Deadpool Corps?

I saw the movie only once so far, but I think if they the Deadpool Corps were not attacking Wolverine or Deadpool there was no reason for them to attack the Deadpool characters from the Corp.  Baby was not attacking, so thinking if Kid was not attacking they did not do anything.

I don't recall ALL of the Corps dying. Didn't they stop fighting when Peter turned up?

@Paulie_D Technically, none of them "die" - they all just regenerate and get back up again - but they all appear to have been killed until that happens. I don't know how to word it any better without making the question too verbose.

I do remember the fighting calming down/stopping before Peter turned up but I believe at that point (before Peter showed up)I all the Deadpool's "died"/were out of commission while healing THEN Peter showed up as they were all healing (at least the ones fighting).

Kidpool survived the initial fight and was seen with the regenerated Deadpools, though her direct involvement in the battle remains unclear.
I didn't spot Kidpool during the main fight scene either, but she does make notable appearances both before and after the fight. Prior to the fight, we see Kidpool, along with the others, running towards Deadpool and Wolverine, seemingly ready to join the fray. This suggests she was prepared to participate in the fight alongside the other Deadpool Corps members.

After the fight, when the regenerated Deadpools are regrouping to face off against Deadpool and Wolverine once more, Kidpool can be seen walking with them.

Her presence becomes even more apparent when Peter enters the scene, prompting Kidpool to exclaim, "That's fucking Peter!"
However, the extent of Kidpool's participation in the battle remains ambiguous. It's possible she was involved in the fight but was "killed" off-screen, only to regenerate later.
Given the film's apparent reluctance to show harm coming to younger characters (as evidenced by Babypool's survival), it's likely that Kidpool's involvement in the fight was intentionally left vague to avoid depicting violence against a child on-screen.

Fair enough. As I mentioned in the question, Deadpool and Wolverine are both reluctant to hurt children, so it's likely Kidpool was spared, but without explicit confirmation I think this is the best answer I'm going to get.
